# What exactly is the sales_flat_quote used for?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, quote, flat

I am a newbie in magento. I understand that when a customer adds something into his cart, all the details regarding the product and customer gets stored into the quote. Why is it necessary to create a quote for an order?

Also I have a script for placing an order programmatically, in which I don't create a quote for the product ordered. Am I making a mistake here without creating a quote? What are the uses of doing so?

Comment: Saving the quote allows logged in customers to come back and order the cart contents later. They can abandon the cart for a period of time and not lose the contents.

Answer (score 1):

A quote in Magento is basically an order that hasn't been placed yet. It contains product items (shopping cart), addresses and payment/shipping methods. It is created as soon as you add an item to cart. During checkout, billing and shipping data is added to the quote. Finally, when the user clicks place order, the quote is converted to an order.

Source : [Magento - Difference between Quote and Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273537/magento-difference-between-quote-and-order)

Comment: What if I dont create a quote and place an order programmatically @pankaj

Comment: yes you create order directly in your custom script by specify setQuoteId to 0